# wordpress edit wp_users table field from admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a field "money" to wp_users table, whehe store a user money amount. Now i want to take ability for admin to change that input field value.

I can get the value with function added to functions.php

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

    function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

      <h3>User money</h3>

      <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
          <th><label for="twitter">Amount</label></th>

          <td>
            <input type="text" name="money" id="money" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'money', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description">Enter user money</span>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    <?php }
```

but how can i update that field?

Comment: Did you see this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I made in such a way

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');

 function update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
     if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )

      $money = $_POST['money'];

      global $wpdb;


      $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_users SET money='$money' WHERE ID = '$user_id'");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');

 function update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
     if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )
         update_user_meta($user_id, 'money', $_POST['money']);
 }
```

Would you please try above code?

Comment: and this add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');
 
 function update_extra_profile_fields($user) {
     if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user->ID) )
         wp_update_user($user->ID, 'money', $_POST['money']);
 }

but dont work :(

Comment: Would you please remove if statement `if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )` after check?